# VBA Word: Create a dropdown ContentControl within a specific cell of a table and populate the dropdown

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

As far as I'm aware within a For loop this will add a row to the bottom of the intended Table.
Then finds the 2nd cell in the bottom most row.
Then adds a dropdown list and names it "Primary Role".
Then sets all the attributes to the contents of the dropdown.
Later it will loop back through here the number of times it takes to have the desired amount a rows.
So that every row has a copy of the same dropdown as the table grows longer.

```vb
'PersonnelTbl.Rows.Add
Set RoleCell = PersonnelTbl.Cell(PersonnelTbl.Rows.Count, 2).Range
With RoleCell.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
    .Title = "Primary Role"
    .SetPlaceHolderText , , "Role"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "A"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "B"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "C"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "D"
End With
```

The issue is these are considered a "Type mismatch":

```vb
.SetPlaceHolderText , , "Role"
.DropdownListEntries.Add "A"
.DropdownListEntries.Add "B"
.DropdownListEntries.Add "C"
.DropdownListEntries.Add "D"
```

If I expand it to it's full proper value of:

```
RoleCell.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList).SetPlaceHolderText , , "Role"
```

It returns as an "Invalid Command"

Do I "copy" the dropdown and paste it into the newly created Cell? Am I just specifying the drop down values wrong for the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I get an "Object required" error on your *With RoleCell* line. Here's a sample of working content control code:

```
Sub AddDropDownCC()
  Dim oCC As ContentControl
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList, Selection.Range)
  With oCC
    .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Role"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Choose an item.", value:=""
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Item 1", "Value 1"
    .DropdownListEntries.Add "Item 2", "Value 2"
  End With
  Set oCC = Nothing
End Sub
```

.DropdownListEntries.Add is expecting 2 strings, 1 for the displayed text and another for the value returned when that text is chosen.

Comment: Didn't seem worth posting another "Answer" as your Answer works. But it seems that if you do not declare RoleCell explicitly as a Range (i.e. Word.Range), then with the OP's code you see the behaviour that the OP describes. I don't know why this should be so because VBA still seems to return the expected "Range" after it has assigned to RoleCell but then the Locals Window does show Variant/Object/Range rather than just Range. I've seen this kind of thing so maybe there's a well-known explanation but I don't know what it is!

Comment: @jonsson: most likely it's due to the fact, that the range is returned from a cell. I usually use a procedure that will apply `rgCell.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1` to the cells range.

Comment: @Jonsson Thank you. After some more searching and new perspective after seeing the new code, apparently SetPlaceHolerText REQUIRES input into each of the 3 variables. Null is not accepted. So I had to explicitly state:

.SetPlaceHolderText Nothing, Nothing, "Roles"

As for the range issues, that happened next but all I had to do was pass the range through the ContentControl.Add (wdCC, Range)